# Hibernate Cascade operation on OneToMany relation gives update query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
public class Parent{

    @Id
    @Column(name="Parentid")
    private String Parentid;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="Parentid" referencedColumnName="Parentid")
    private List<Child> objChild;
    .....//getters and setters
}
```

Child uses composite primary key. and the code for that is:-

```
@Embeddable
public class ChildPk{

    @Column(name="...")
    private String str1;

    @Column(name="...")
    private String str2;
    .....//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class Child{

    @Column(name="Parentid", nullable="false")
    private String Parentid;  //this the foriegn key referencing Entity1

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPk objChildPk;

    .....//getters and setters
}
```

As per the above code, i have a Parent to Child one-to-many relationship. And the Child contains a Composite key as its Primary Key.

I populate the Child with a composite key, add it to Parent, Populate Parent, and save Parent with session.save(). This execute insert statement on Child successfully. Same way, if i try to insert another Child object but containing same composite key as earlier but different foreign key and then try to save again the Parent object, it actually updates the existing row in Child with new Parentid.

As per relational database, my understanding was that duplicate entry of composite key in Child table should fail to insert. But, Hibernate is updating the existing row because values are same (??). I tried inserting different values for composite key and it inserts fine in Child table.

I hope i am trying to make you understand the problem correctly. There is a unidirectional one-to-many relation between two tables where updates are happening with rows that have same values.

I am confused is it a problem of one-to-many or of composite key.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you are doing? It's very hard to follow this description.

Comment: I don't understand how the composite PK has anything to do with the association between both entities. But your mapping is wrong: `table2.myid` is mapped twice: once as JoinColumn in Entity1, and once as a column in Entity2. Remove the field from Entity2, or make the association bidirectional.